# When are these events raised, and how are they related? "CommandManager.CanExecute and CanExecute of CommandBinding

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

When are these events raised, and how are they related?   "CommandManager.CanExecute  and CanExecute of CommandBinding???

Answer (score 1):

The `CanExecute` event of a `CommandBinding` is fired when the `CommandBinding` believes something changed that could affect the state of the command. This is primarily when the user interacts with the UI in some way (mouse moves, clicks, focus changes, etc.), or when a user action causes a `PropertyChanged` or `CollectionChanged` event.  This event does *not* get fired when your code changes something in the UI, or causes a `PropertyChanged` event to fire.

Is there a specific situation you have in mind?

The `CommandManager.CanExecute` method is a way to attach a `CanExecute` event handler to a UI element, so that when the `CanExecute` of the `RoutedUICommand` bubbles up the visual tree, it can trigger your `CanExecute` event handler. It is just a different way to attach a `CanExecute` event to an element for different scenarios, but the end result is the same as adding a `CommandBinding` to the `CommandBindings` collection of a `UIElement`.